# Modification to mySQL query to show empty rows at the end, not at the top while using ASC

Tags: php, mysql

In my mysql table the column `contact` is either empty or it has a date.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE eidos='AETOS' order by  contact asc";
```

My goal is to show the closer `contact` dates at the top.

For now, it shows me all the rows that have no date at the top, and at the end those rows that have a `contact` date are shown ascending, the smaller date at the top.

How to show at the top the rows that have `contact` date in ascending, followed by the empty rows?

Comment: By _empty_, do you mean `NULL`?

Comment: its does not write NULL, it is just empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple conditions in your `ORDER BY` statement.  Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cars
WHERE eidos='AETOS'
ORDER BY contact is null, contact asc
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb145/1)

---

Edit -- if the value is not `null`, but just an empty string, you can do that by changing `contact is null'` to `'contact = ''`.  And if you don't know, you could always wrap `coalesce` around it:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cars
WHERE eidos='AETOS'
ORDER BY COALESCE(id,'') = '', contact asc
```

- [More Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4df89/2)

Comment: @Fataoulas -- look at the answer and I bet you could answer that one!  `ORDER BY COALESCE(id,'') = '', contact asc, timestamp desc` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple where clauses to select the correct "eidos" matches as well as only the rows that are not empty.

```
select  * 
from Cars 
WHERE eidos = 'AETOS'
ORDER BY contact ASC
GROUP BY contact
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE eidos='AETOS' order by  case when contact in ('',0) then 1 else 0 end, contact asc";
```